# Workbook Links Refresh

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

I have a program that makes copies of a workbook. The original workbook (book1) has links in it that I want to preserve to a separate workbook (book2) that is password protected. I have a program in book2 that will open and update the copy of book1. However, the copy(book3) keeps asking to update the link anytime I open it.

I know how to go to Data->Workbook Links->Settings->Don't Refresh to turn it off, but this setting in book1 isn't saved when I use my program to make book3 and I don't want to constantly have to update this for every book3 I make. I also have tried to use a Private Sub Workbook_Open macro in book1 that will safely open book2 to update values but that Macro for some reason isn't working in book3

Is there anything I can change to stop this or a method of Saving book1 that fix this.

Comment: After some research, I've found this method that can update a workbook but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for. Here's the forumla : ```Wk.UpdateLink Name:=Wk.LinkSources```